# Creating a new tableview when search an item iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am adding search bar in a view. When i click on search bar, i am creating a tableview. When i enter text on search bar, it filter from the list and display it in new tableview. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I am removing tableview from view but its removing only one. I am using following code.

```
if(!_storeListTableView)
{
    _storeListTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5  , 100, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _storeListTableView.delegate = self;
    _storeListTableView.dataSource = self;
    _storeListTableView.tag = 2;
    _storeListTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    _storeListTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _storeListTableView.rowHeight = 45.f;
    [_storeListTableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
    _storeListTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_storeListTableView];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_storeListTableView removeFromSuperview];
    _storeListTableView = nil; 
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(_storeListTableView.tag == 2 && isFiltered == TRUE)
{
    if([searchData count] > 0 && [searchData count] > indexPath.row)
    {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
else if(_storeListTableView.tag == 2 && isFiltered == FALSE)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [finalStoreListFromServer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to create two tableview. You should maintain two array and just reload tableview

Comment: i am not creating two table view. When enter text on search bar it creates new and displaying it

Comment: have you tried to add `[tableView removeFromSuperView];` in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`? This method gives this `tableView` object you can remove from superView.

Comment: what do you want exactly? specify your requirement

Comment: You don't need to create and remove table views on your own when implementing search functionality in your app. There is already a UISearchDisplayController that you can use for search purposes. This tutorial is a bit outdated but the search principles should still hold: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view If you want to see the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/

Comment: @Bhanu Priya why it is creating two tableview? when i run app there is no tableview.  When i click on search button i am creating tableview, till now is fine. When i start search an item its creating new tableview on top of the tableview. My problem is when i select row at indexpath it should remove. but only one is getting removed which i created  when pressing search button.

Comment: @Bhanu Priya halileohalilei Please check i edited my post.

Comment: Follow halileohalilei's comment. He is right. There is no need for two tableviews altough you need two arrays and make a reload in case of a search.